# Kendo Grid MVC: Change a value in all rows with a master checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox, kendo-grid

First of all, I'm a javascript noob, so my code is neither pretty nor smart. :(

I have a pretty basic Kendo grid to which I added two columns. The first column contains a checkbox (I call them minionCheckBox), the second contains a bool (from the data source), I'll call this one isChecked and the default is set to false.

Also I have a masterCheckBox in the table header which should toggle all minions.

Both checkbox types are added like this:

```js
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVC5KendoTestWeb.Models.DTOs.DTO_User>()
        .Name("TestGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                .HeaderTemplate("<input class='checkbox masterCheckBox' type='checkbox' /> <strong>Alle</strong>")
                .ClientTemplate(@"
                    <input class='checkbox minionCheckBox' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: isChecked' #= isChecked ? checked='checked' : '' # />")
                .Width(80);
            columns.Bound(cn => cn.isChecked).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "isChecked" });
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Create(create => create.Action("CreateUserData", "XXX"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("ReadUserData", "XXX"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateUserData", "XXX"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyUserData", "XXX"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(cn => cn.ID);
            })
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(true)
        )
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
)
```

I want to change the value of isChecked whenever I toggle the checkbox in the same row. This seems to work as I intended with the following code:

```js
var grid = $("#TestGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.tbody.on("change", function (e) {
    var isMinionChecked = $(e.target).prop("checked");
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    if (isMinionChecked) {
        item.set("isChecked", true);
    } else {
        item.set("isChecked", false);
    }
    if (!item.isChecked) {
        var isMasterChecked = $(".masterCheckBox").prop("checked");
        if (isMasterChecked) {
            $('.masterCheckBox').prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
})
```

And here is my problem: Now I want to do the same for all rows whenever I check the masterCheckBox. This is my code for that:

```js
var grid = $("#TestGrid").data("kendoGrid");
$(".masterCheckBox").on("click", function () {
  var isMasterChecked = $(".masterCheckBox").prop("checked");
  grid.table.find(".minionCheckBox").each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    if (isMasterChecked) {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
      item.set("isChecked", true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
      item.set("isChecked", false);
    }
  })
})
```

But, it only toggles the checkbox in the first row and sets the isChecked in that row to true. When I remove the two item.set lines, it works perfectly and checks or unchecks all checkboxes.

I know the code is not perfect yet and also I need to add a few more things, but as I see it, this should at least do these two things by now: toggle all checkboxes and set all isChecked fields to the right value.

Can someone help me figure this one out?

Comment: Okay, and here is the solution I found myself. Yeah, that's right. I found it. Not you my fellow stackers … or overflowers … or whatever you call yourselves these days. Get down on your knees and hail me for I found the holy grail of … Kendo … Checkbox thingies … ugh, whatever, here's the solution. Question closed.

Well, this is awkward. The solution is down there, yeah … so … don't mind me, I'm just … oh look, a kitten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function toggleCheckbox() {
    $(".masterCheckBox").on("click", function (e) {
        var grid = $("#TestGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var ds = grid.dataSource.data();
        var isMasterChecked = $(".masterCheckBox").prop("checked");

        for (var i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
            var dataItem = ds[i];
            dataItem.isChecked = isMasterChecked;
        }
        grid.refresh();
    })
}

function registerOnChangeEvent() {
    var grid = $("#TestGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.tbody.on("change", function (e) {
        var isMinionChecked = $(e.target).prop("checked");
        var isMasterChecked = $(".masterCheckBox").prop("checked");
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var item = grid.dataItem(row);
        var oldChecked = item.get("isChecked");
        if (isMinionChecked != oldChecked) {
            item.set("isChecked", isMinionChecked);
        }

        if (!isMinionChecked && isMasterChecked) {
            $('.masterCheckBox').prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
}
```